# What use are the Nature Sprites?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I've been introduced to the Nature Sprites, and met them all.  In previous Harvest Moon games, they used to help you out with things, such as unlocking new areas in A New Beginning, or using them as slave labour in HM:DS (They'll do anything, if they like you.  They also *really* liked flour.  To an unhealthy degree).

What is their purpose in Story of Seasons?  Can they help you with chores on your farm?

Comment: they probably help you out just the same as the game goes on. after just meeting them nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [thread on this topic](http://fogu.com/hmforum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=165755) on the Ushi No Tane forums, they apparently they don't help on the farm or do anything else useful. They'll show up again when Dessie, basically this game's Harvest Goddess, shows up in Spring of the second year. You can interact with them normally then, including giving them gifts, but they don't seem to have any other purpose.

Comment: it seems nobody on that forum is too sure either, they are probably super lategame stuff